# Find an infinite collection of maximal ideals containing $(x^2 - y^3) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

What is an infinite collection of maximal ideals containing the ideal $I = (x^2 - y^3) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Comment: Maximal ideals are points. So...?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, yes yes every maximal ideal of algebraically closd field is of the form (xi−ai)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For every $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ consider the ideal
$$ (x-\alpha^3,y-\alpha^2) \subset \mathbb C[x,y].$$
Can you show that every ideal of this form contains $I$?

Comment: Do I just write it as a combination of the generators?

Comment: Yes. Can you write $(x^2-y^3)=p(x,y)(x-\alpha^3)+q(x,y)(y-\alpha^2)$?

Comment: Sec, high school algebra....

Comment: So I fiddled with it and I found that there isn't really anyway to get rid of $-x\alpha^3$ or $-\alpha^3y^2$ term (on phone, going to get to a comp later to answer)

Comment: take $p(x,y)=(x+\alpha^3)$ and $q(x,y)=y^2+\alpha^2y+\alpha^4$

Comment: But how you get it...? Is it trial and error?

Comment: no. Just observe that $x-\alpha^3$ divides $x^2-\alpha^6$ and $y-\alpha^2$ divides $y^3-\alpha^6$.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz: suppose $(x^2-y^3)$ is contained in a maximal ideal $(x-a,x-b)$. Then we can write $x^2-y^3=p (x-a)+q (y-b)$ for polynomials $p,q$ and evaluating at $(a,b)$ gives that $a^2=b^3$. So your task is the same as showing the zero locus of $x^2-y^3$ is infinite. This is true since $\Bbb C$ is infinite and every pair $(z^3,z^2)$ lies in the zero locus of this polynomial.

Comment: Oh that's better than me coming up with my own $p$ and $q$....

Comment: The OP has asked for infinitely many maximal ideals containing a given ideal. Why need Nullstellensatz in order to produce such ideals?

Comment: @user26857 I just wanted to stress the fact one should think about points in this case, and then it is more or less intuitive why there are infinitely many points: the curve $x^2=y^3$ consists of infinitely many points in $\Bbb C^2$.